# Azure App service odd remote debugging error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

Trying to debug an app service remotely and some of the methods are erroring out on a very weird point. Specifically declaring and setting an int or string variable. This is only happening on one of our team members machine's and no one else can reproduce it.

the line in question:  `int compId = 0;`

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at InfoSecToolkit.Controllers.UserController.isLDAPUserGranted(Int32 TypeId) in C:\Users\cesar.balangue_infos\source\repos\InfoSecToolkit-GIT\InfoSecToolkit\Controllers\UserController.cs:line 736
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

> the line in question: int compId = 0;

There are different causes for the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` .

- It indicates that your code is trying to work with an object that has a null value as its reference.
- To resolve this you might need to change the value `0` to `“??”`

For more information please refer this [**`Blog`**](https://www.stechies.com/object-reference-not-set-instance-object/#1) for similar issues.

To remote debug in Azure please refer this [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-azure?view=vs-2022) .